# Why is this simple ready() Javascript code not running inside the <body> HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ready

Inside my `<body>` HTML tags, I have the following test code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Document Ready!');
    });
</script>
```

However, it does nothing when I load the page.  Yet, if I paste the code that's in-between the `<script>` tags into the Chrome console, it works.

So it's not a syntax issue and I can't wrap my head around why it's failing.

Comment: Try putting your script in a separate script element rather than the same element you are using to download jquery.

Comment: Have one script for jQuery import, then another with your js